# What to do when test values are not correlated with predictions?

Tags: regression

I have a regression problem where I obtained a mean absolute error close to the desired value but the predictions do not correlate well with the expected values. I have tried several algorithms, paired them with GridSearchCV as well.

A low error in a regression problem is meaningless if these two variables are not correlated right?

Here is the best result:

[image: regression]

Comment: What do you mean that the mean absolute error is close to the desired value?

Comment: @Dave the problem I am trying to solve was tried earlier by others and their notebooks seem to achieve a value similar to mine so I guessed I achieved the desired value but none of them made this figure

Comment: If that kind of mean absolute error can be achieved without the predictions having much to do with the true values, then they’ve not held themselves to a very high standard, have they? It’s good that your work is achieving performance comparable to what others have achieved, but that seems to be a pretty minimal achievement. How is the performance if you fit an intercept-only model? Is it better or worse than what you and the others achieved?

Comment: So far I've tried HistGradientBoostingRegressor, XGBRegressor, LinearRegression, RandomForest, SVR, PolynomialFeatures. all have similar or worse graph like above.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you shouldn't conclude the quality of your model from *scatterplot* alone. It happened to me many times when I saw the scatterplot and thought that predicted~actual is really poor. In many cases, it turns out that 99% of your prediction is very close to actual ones, but there is a "cloud" of poor prediction that overlays it. The solution is that you should use ***hist2d*** to depict this relation or as a background for your scatterplot. It will show whether there is a part of points very close expected line.

It might not show that your model is great, but it might explain why you see great prediction metrics. I think it should be your anchor point for further analysis. If this scenario comes true, an imbalanced dataset might be an issue.

Your results also resemble a predicted~actual chart I got once when y was randomly assigned to random X values because of a silly mistake. It's always a good idea to double-check your code.